# Book about a girl searching for her father in a world Roma came from

Tags: story-identification, books, parallel-universe

My friend read this book and can’t remember the name and I’ve been trying to find it too with no luck and I was hoping you lovely people might be able to help. Here’s what I know:

- It was clearly stated that the main characters were Roma/Romani
- plot was basically that this girl's father went missing, and it turned out he'd opened a gate to another world
- she meets this Rromani teenager named Rafe
- and they go to the other world together to rescue her father
- and it turns out that Rafe’s group of Rromani were originally from this other world and he's the prince of it
- Rafe ends up staying, but the girl rescues her dad and brings him home

And that’s all I know!

Comment: Welcome to CV, Audie Lee. Your first few items had me thinking *The Golden Compass*, but then not. I hope someone IDs your book!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did your friend read this book?

Comment: I wasn't aware that India was another world, but you learn something new every day.